# Ubuntu 18.04.1 Intel 9260, beginner question

Tags: networking, drivers, 18.04, intel

I recently switched to Ubuntu, at least with a dual-boot on my laptop to learn the environment and test it before switching. As a developer, I think as an operating system, it will work better for me.

For now, I need to learn a lot more, especially in configuration terms.

Using Windows, it was pretty easy to install drivers which I liked to in the device-manager, but I just do not find a possibility to install the driver found on Intels page https://www.intel.de/content/www/de/de/support/articles/000005511/network-and-i-o/wireless-networking.html. Somewhere somebody wrote that I just need to put it in /etc/firmware/, and I did, but Ubuntu doesn't care.

Following the output for "sudo lshw -C network".

```
*-network                 
       Beschreibung: Kabellose Verbindung
       Produkt: Intel Corporation
       Hersteller: Intel Corporation
       Physische ID: 0
       Bus-Informationen: pci@0000:07:00.0
       Logischer Name: wlp7s0
       Version: 29
       Seriennummer: b4:6b:fc:6b:5a:e9
       Breite: 64 bits
       Takt: 33MHz
       Fähigkeiten: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       Konfiguration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=4.15.0-36-generic firmware=34.0.0 ip=192.168.178.39 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       Ressourcen: irq:18 memory:d1600000-d1603fff
  *-network
       Beschreibung: Ethernet interface
       Produkt: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       Hersteller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       Physische ID: 0
       Bus-Informationen: pci@0000:08:00.0
       Logischer Name: enp8s0
       Version: 0c
       Seriennummer: 30:65:ec:6e:8a:a4
       Größe: 10Mbit/s
       Kapazität: 1Gbit/s
       Breite: 64 bits
       Takt: 33MHz
       Fähigkeiten: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       Konfiguration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=half firmware=rtl8168g-2_0.0.1 02/06/13 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII speed=10Mbit/s
       Ressourcen: irq:31 ioport:3000(Größe=256) memory:d1500000-d1500fff memory:d1400000-d1403fff
```

At this point, I do not know if the provided driver of Intel are used, but I get a poor performance of my wifi. Right now, I am sitting 2 meters away from my wifi router, but can not get full signal.

What should I do? I would appreciate any help to get me started correctly. Thanks in advance. This post is created because of desperation after couple of days of searching and testing. (I've read the introduction and overview on ubuntu-wiki, but it's not explaining the deep stuff, which I want to improve myself in in the beginning to avoid bad mistakes in the long term)

Bonus: Is there any kind of working hibernation for Ubuntu 18.04.1? These two points are annoying and pretty important for me. Is there any other stuff you can recommend, I should make like for better power-management, better graphical performance (Intel HD 4600 I think and Nvidia GTX 960m).

Comment: I think you will have much better luck asking about hibernation in a seperate question.

Comment: Yeah you're right. Im on it.

Answer (score 0):

Your device appears to be using the correct driver, *iwlwifi* and the correct -34 firmware.

In my experience, having used many Intel devices myself over 15 years, the firmware and driver *iwlwifi* are seldom the issue. I suggest that the solution is likely related to either:

- Power saving;
- The device wants to roam from among several SSIDs with the same name; for example, eduroam;
- The router is set to autoselect the encryption; that is WPA or WPA2, and the wireless device stumbles at the changeover;
- The router is set to autoselect the channel and the device also stumbles at the changeover; or
- The router is set to TKIP.

You can address the power saving issue with a terminal command:

```
sudo sed -i 's/3/2/' /etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/* && sudo service network-manager restart
```

Please address each issue and tell us if there is any improvement.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. I have checked the points with SSID and the wifi network related stuff. It is all well, except that the router is automatically choosing the channels. Only WPA2 is active, without TKIP. I applied the sed stuff, but nothing changed. I do not understand what you mean with Power saving. Is there an option like in Windows to deny power saving options of wifi, so there is always the most possible signal?

Comment: Here is a good discussion of why you don't want any auto channel selection: https://superuser.com/questions/1311149/why-do-wifi-routers-do-such-a-bad-job-of-channel-selection  Please choose a fixed channel if possible; I suggest 1, 6 or 11. The power saving denies the wireless the ability to shut down to conserve power, particularly battery power, as most Linux wireless devices have trouble seamlessly reconnecting upon wake-up.

Comment: Hi chili555, I changed the auto-channel option to channel 11. The result is the same. Wifi still not full signal. Another idea?

Comment: What does this report? `nmcli dev wifi list` Are the speedtest results correspondingly low? http://www.speedtest.net